# filter my array on column 3 for a specific word

Tags: arrays, vba, filter

I have the following code below,

I want to filter the array (not the sheet) for the word "phone" which sits in column 3 of the array. The output would then go to my destination sheet("L")

how would i modify the code below to filter for the word? I must state i want to filter the array not the sheet.

```
Sub Example1()
Dim arrValues() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim filteredArray()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim alength As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
arrValues = Sheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 21)).Value
ReDim filteredArray(1 To UBound(arrValues), 1 To 1)
alength = UBound(arrValues)
For lCount = 1 To UBound(arrValues) Step 1
   lRow = lRow + 1
   filteredArray(lRow, 1) = arrValues(lCount, 1)
Next
Sheets("L").Range("A2:U" & 1 + alength) = filteredArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filteredArray()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim tempArray()

    lastRow = Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Raw Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    arrValues = Sheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 21)).Value

    ' First use a temporary array with just one dimension
    ReDim tempArray(1 To UBound(arrValues))
    For lCount = 1 To UBound(arrValues)
        If arrValues(lCount, 3) = "phone" Then
            lRow = lRow + 1
            tempArray(lRow) = arrValues(lCount, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Now we know how large the filteredArray needs to be: copy the found values into it
    ReDim filteredArray(1 To lRow, 1 To 1)
    For lCount = 1 To lRow
        filteredArray(lCount, 1) = tempArray(lCount)
    Next

    Sheets("L").Range("A2:U" & 1 + lRow) = filteredArray
End Sub
```

Comment: @ trincot Hey thanks for your reply, this looks really good, if i were then to filter column 3 for the word "phone" and want to bring back the entire row of the array is it this bit of code i would have to alter to a Range? tempArray(lRow) = arrValues(lCount, 2)

Comment: No, you would take out the `if ... = "phone"` condition, and always execute what is currently in that block. If I may say, what you did here can be done via Excel formulas only without the need of macros. I will not go into that here, as it is a different question, and not trivial, but I stronly suggest googling it. A non-macro solution is to be preferred as it needs no confirmation from the user to run, nor does it mark the workbook as modified when the filter is applied, resulting in "Do you want to save changes?" ... etc.